# C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, visual-studio-2012, conditional-statements

C# Program Determining if a number is either a multiple of ten or within a particular set of ranges

I have a few loops that I need in my program. I can also write out the c# code but I'm not entirely sure how to write them logically.

I need Program that will enter 10 numbers and display the count of number according to ranges. Ranges are 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50, Greater than 50: OUT OF RANGE. [using conditional and looping statement]

and the second one is Program that will display the following output [using conditional and looping statement]
Sequence: A is multiplied to B and added to C.
Just like this:

```
A   B   C
1   2   1
2   4   3
3   6   5
4   8   7
5   10  9
6   12  11
7   14  13
8   16  15
9   18  17
10  20  19

Output
3
11
23
39
59
83
111
143
179
219
```

This is for a snakes and ladders board game, if it makes any more sense for my question.

I imagine the first if statement  can write it out like if (num > 10 && num is < 21 || etc) but there has to be something smarter than that be correct?

The second one I have no idea.

Comment: :-/ Where are code? I m wanting to saw code.

Comment: if ((num > 10 && num <= 20) ||
    (num > 30 && num <= 40) ||
    (num > 50 && num <= 60) ||
    (num > 70 && num <= 80) ||
    (num > 90 && num <= 100)) {
 
} but i think this is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start with the largest number first, something like:

```
foreach(number in positiveNumberArray)
{
    if (number > 50)
        Console.WriteLine("Out of Range");
    else if(number > 40)
        Console.WriteLine("Range 40-50");
    else if(number > 30)
        Console.WriteLine("Range 30-40");
    else if(number > 20)
        Console.WriteLine("Range 20-30");
    else if(number > 10)
        Console.WriteLine("Range 10-20");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Range 0-10");
}
```

### Edit:

To count the up the numbers in each range, try something like:

```
int [] count = new int[6];
foreach(number in positiveNumberArray)
{
    if (number > 50)
        count[5]++;
    else if(number > 40)
        count[4]++;
    else if(number > 30)
        count[3]++;
    else if(number > 20)
        count[2]++;
    else if(number > 10)
        count[1]++;
    else
        count[0]++;
}
Console.WriteLine(" > 50: {0}", count[5]);
Console.WriteLine("40-50: {0}", count[4]);
Console.WriteLine("30-40: {0}", count[3]);
Console.WriteLine("20-30: {0}", count[2]);
Console.WriteLine("10-20: {0}", count[1]);
Console.WriteLine("0-10: {0}", count[0]);
```

> Please take this solution as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.